# Customer Login Doesn't work (Magento EE-1.14.2.0)

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies, authentication

**System and enviroment:** 
Magento EE-1.14.2.0, 
Using secure urls on front-end (for customer login, checkout page and payment page.). SSL is working as it should. No console errors on customer login page.

**Session Cookie Management Setup**

1. Cookie Lifetime: 7200 
   *tried changing it to 33600, doesn't solve the problem*
2. Cookie Path: (blank)
3. Cookie Domain: .mydomain.com 
   *when it is blank, problem is the same*
4. Use HTTP Only: NO
5. Cookie Restriction Mode: NO

**Problem:** 
When customer tries to login (with valid username and password) he gets redirected to login page without error message and without logging in as well. If customer uses wrong username or password he will be redirected to login page and error will be displayed.

**One of solutions:** 
Set Session Cookie Management -> HTTP only to YES. And in this case, even if customer is logging over HTTPS, he will be logged in. I find this strange, since customer is using HTTPS protocol. Shouldn't this be set to no in this case?

Note: Customer cookies (CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_AUTH, CUSTOMER_INFO, CUSTOMER_RATES) are not in Resources when customer tries to login.

**Question:** 
Should be HTTP only be set to NO if users are logging over https protocol? And if it shouldn't, should that cause problems like this one?